# Internal ID of e-mail template in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to send e-mail from netsuite using API function nlapiMergeRecord in suitelet.
But the problem is i am not being able to search the Internal ID of templates that i will be using. 
Can anyone tell me how can i get Internal ID of an e-mail template?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the easiest way I have found.

First, make sure your preferences has show internal ID. To do this, go Home>Set Preferences>under the General Tab on the right make sure "Show Internal IDs" is checked.

If this is done, then go to Documents>Templates>Email Templates and it will show the internal ID in the list.

If you recently made the Template, a quick-tip is to sort by internal ID descending in the list and the most recent Template will be shown. If it isn't a new template, I use just good ole' Ctrl+F to search my list of Templates if I know it's name.

Please mark this answer as "correct" if it helped you do what you needed.